# Avoid compiling when using Decimal.Round() method (C#/CF)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, compact-framework, compiler-errors

Is there a way to tell to VS2005 to get compiler error when using "some defined" method?

It probably sounds strange, but I do not want to compile when using Decimal.Round().

**Reason:**
CF does not round by "awayfromzero", so I created a method to do this job. 
But sometimes I (and team) forget that is not to use Decimal.Round. So I'd like to get a compiler error when using it.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this with the compiler.

[FXCop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FxCop), however, could easily be set up with a rule about it.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any way to do this, but you could create an extension method of the Decimal class.  Something like `Decimal.RoundAwayFromZero()`.  That might be easier to remember since you will see it in Intellisense.

Comment: +1 for an elegant solution, I wish we weren't targetting .NET CF 2.0 :( I'm running into the same issue as OP alot and it's tricky not to let it slip through tests